# AWS Lambda in R and S3 event trigger

Tags: r, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda in R that does some data analysis based on files in S3 bucket. I have the Lambda working successfully. I am now trying to trigger the Lambda from S3 when new files are put. However after adding the S3 event trigger on the Lambda when I put a new file in S3 bucket, I am seeing errors in the Lambda

ERROR:runtime:error: unused argument ...
Any pointers on how to fix the error and invoke the Lambda function successfully?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you pass some parameters not needed by your function.